# What is the name of this AC power outlet?

Tags: plug, outlet

I have these power outlets on the ceiling in a (newly built) house in Sweden, they are meant for lamps. I could not find any information on them, what is their name?

Power outlet with plug. The hole/pole distance is around 11.5 mm center to center.
[image: Power outlet with plug]

Size comparison with CEE/Schuko plug
[image: Size comparison with CEE/Schuko plug]

Comment: It's an AC power outlet as far as I'm concerned. You might want to use the phrase AC socket too.

Comment: @Andy: Didn't I write that in the title?

Comment: Yes you did and it seemed like a very appropriate name.

Comment: But that does not help me to find the exact name for buying cables with the corresponding plug. I am obviously looking for a more precise type name.

Comment: Well it's no-good complaining to me because obviously I can't help any further. Anyway your question was about the outlet name and not the names of cables or plugs. How far from the nearest hardware store are you?

Comment: Well outlet implies plug. I was at the hardware store yesterday, I could not find it there (it was a small one though).

Comment: Not according to the description of your top photograph - you state "Power outlet with plug". I bet Ikea have some.

Comment: This does not directly match any standard socket, but it looks like a non-standard version of the type C socket/plug. The metal pole on the wall socket does not connect to anything on the plug, so it is just a two pos unpolarized connection (the metal pole on wall outlet seems like just there for mechanical stability?). I'd bet that a type C plug would fit in there fine. Measure the distance between the two holes/poles then check it against a type C plug.

Comment: @Andy: Maybe this is a misunderstanding then (I am not a native speaker of English)? In the top photograph I would call the left thing a "plug" and the right thing an "outlet". What are their proper names?

Comment: @I.Wolfe The pole distance is 11.5 mm (you can also see from my second picture that the type C would not fit, since the pole distance of those is as far as I know compatible with the CEE 7/7 which I think I have in my picture).

Comment: Well, it's some kind on non-standard ungrounded plug. I would contact the lamp manufacturer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lamppropp which plugs in to a [lamputtag,](http://www.eldirekt.se/elmaterial/eluttag/lamputtag) which I take to mean "lamp plug" for a "lamp outlet."

The link contains pictures of both, including a lamputtag that is a dead ringer for yours.
Now you know what to ask for when you go to the hardware store, or when you shop on line for one.

Those connectors seem to be a specialty of Sweden, designed to make it easier (safer) for a non-electrician to connect a ceiling lamp.

---

That said, this would probably have been better on [the DIY Stackexchange site.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/)